# Knockout Options Binding get Value

Tags: knockout.js

I'm struggling to get the selected values of an options binding.

Here's the (simplified) code:

HTML

```
  <div data-bind="foreach:organizations" class="accordion " id="accordionOrg">
       [...]
    <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Billing Address</th>
             [...]
             <th></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr> 
             <td>
               <select data-bind="options: organizationAddresses, optionsText: 'address', value:'organizationAddressId'"></select> 
             </td>
             <td>
                <div data-bind="click: $root.addOrg" class="btn btn-small  btn-block"></div>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Each organization has a ICollection of adresses:
C# Model

```
public class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SapId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrganizationAddress> OrganizationAddresses { get; set; }

}
```

Viewmodel:

```
var organizations = ko.observableArray(); 
var vm = {
    organizations: organizations,
    activate: activate        
};

return vm;

function addOrg(organization) {
   //here I need the selected value
}
```

Everything is working I just dont know how to get the selected value.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: At a glance, I see that you probably want to use `optionsValue` binding parameter for `organizationAddressId`. You refer to both value and values ... do you want a single address or multiple.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion. I want a single address. I referred to 'values' as in my app the user can chose multiple addresses (billing, delivery etc). I omitted the other <select>'s for simplicity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah lol I was thinking too far...I completely forgot about Jquery. With the

> optionsValue

Binding I can get the value with:

```
 $('#' + organization.organizationId()).val();
```

Thx for your input Origineil!
Somtimes you have to write down the question to find the answer :)

Comment: If you don't want to use jquery I have setup a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/5tGDn/). Essentially, you add an observable into each organization to hold the selected address type (or perhaps manipulate the organizational model to separate the array of addresses into individual addresses by type--I can't tell if your `ICollection<OrganizationAddress>` stores available or selected addresses or both). You access the "current" organization by using the `as` alias. Then your `Add` button doesn't need any additional information that has not already been set by your knockout bindings.